# Can't typeset guillemets in Russian beamer presentation

Tags: beamer, punctuation, russian

I can't seem to produce guillemets (angle quotes) inside of a `beamer` frame, I get the error  message

```
<to be read again> 
                   <
l.9 \end{frame}
```

for the following MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
<<Привет>>
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Somewhat surprisingly if I delete the `\begin{frame}` and `\end{frame}` commands, it works just fine: I get a page with the word "Привет" in the top left enquoted with guillemets. I, however, need to use them within one of many slides.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is that the `frame` environment is looking for an action specification, which are given as `<...>`. So you need to stop the scanning: add a `\relax`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}\relax
<<Привет>>
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Or use the unicode chars for the two symbols (which is not always easy to insert, my Linux with compose key knows how)

Comment: Thank you, both `\relax` and the unicode characters seem to work for me. Do I understand correctly that I would need to add a `\relax` inside of, say, every `itemize` item, since `\item` restarts the scanning you mention?

Comment: @imakhlin if you're using something like `\item <<a>> ` then yes. Might even be better to switch to `csquotes` and just use `\item \enquote{a}` instead (then also the type is not hardwired into the document body)

Comment: @imakhlin Anywhere that can immediately be followed by a `<` will need you to use some form of 'protection'. daleif's approach would be mine too: use logical mark-up for the quotes, and the problem goes away.